# Yii framework set and get functions

Tags: php, yii

I have model Comment extends CActiveRecord and I defined a new variable private $_postTitle = NULL; and I have the following code in the model as explained in the page http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/

```
public function getPostTitle()
{
    if ($this->_postTitle === null && $this->post !== null)
    {
        $this->_postTitle = $this->post->title;
    }
    return $this->_postTitle;
}

public function setPostTitle($value)
{
    $this->_postTitle = $value;
}
```

my question is what is the purpose of the code

> && $this->post !== null

if I  omit this code I wont get the results. so how  && $this->post !== null actually works in this model ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->post !== null
```

It's just guarding you from "Trying to read property of null object exception".

I guess it's very unlikely but maybe it can happen that you have a comment without a post, and if you try to read post's title, its will crash because post is equal to null.

I hope i managed to explain

Comment: If I omit this code, then the page returns error "Trying to get property of non-object" but all my records has post title, so no need to check for $this->post is null or not

Answer (score 0):

The way I see, `$this->post` is a relation with another model.
The `$this->post !== null` is checking if this relation really exist.

If you omit the checking even is that model don't have a relation working, the code will try to get the title `$this->post` returning a error.